# how to include both 'near' and 'where' methods in geo-queries using geofirestore library

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native, geofirestore

I am trying to get near by 'online' users withing the radius of 25km and I am using following code to execute geo queries using geofirestore-js plugin (https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore-js)

```
const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(Firebase.firestore());
const geocollection = geofirestore.collection('location');
const query = geocollection.near({ center: coordinates, radius: 25 }).where('status' , '==' , 'online');
        query.onSnapshot(querysnapshot => {
            let nearByContact = []
            querysnapshot.docs.forEach((change) => {
                if (change.id !== store.user.uid) {
                    nearByContact.push({
                        coordinate: {
                            latitude: change.data().coordinates._latitude,
                            longitude: change.data().coordinates._longitude,
                        },
                        title: change.data().name,
                        description: change.distance.toFixed(2) + " km away",
                        image: change.data().avatarUrl,
                        profileId: change.id
                    })
                }
            })
```

It returns null when using both 'near' and 'where' methods. But the query works well with individual methods like this.

```
const query = geocollection.near({ center: coordinates, radius: 25 })
        query.onSnapshot(querysnapshot => {.....
```

I want to query the firestore db by both the methods Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. instead of using  **query.onSnapshot** on above query i changed it to 
    query.get().then(querysnapshot => ...

Then suddenly the error appeared on debug console by saying that it requires Firestore index

```
Error: [firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: ......
```

Then I created the index in Firestore and revert back the changes I did to query (changed `query.get().then(querysnapshot => {...` to `query.onSnapshot(querysnapshot => {...`) .. It started working after that